# Azure Functions - App Service Plan (Intermittent Slow Calls)

Tags: c, azure, azure-functions

We are using Azure Functions. We are running on  App Service Plan (not consumption model). My issue is that we are seeing a strange delay on 'some' web calls into out services.

For example i have one http get trigger, it returns a list of objects from another web service (so there is outbound web traffic from my function). If i call the service 10 times. i'll get maybe 6 respoonses come back in bewteen 400 and 600 ms)  but then 4 of those calls will take bewteen 7000 and 8000 ms). Its actually quite consitent in the number. It seems bizarre , its either half a second or 7.5 seconds. I have tested the backend system and its not that. So its something around the function app itself.  Any thoughts or suggestions welcome.

Comment: How do you measure the durations? Which durations does the log show? What's the dependency call duration in those cases?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. We call functions from api gateway . I can see the call times there (it shows backend call taking x ms). I Haven proven the service takes under a second to call.

Comment: Sorry I mean I have proven the service call I make from the function take a less than a second outside the function.

Comment: I mean you that you can measure it from different angles. And we can't...

Comment: Go to the Kudu Console on your function app, use curl or Invoke-WebRequest a few times in a row and see if the behavior repros.  There could be some throttling applied by the remote for public cloud IP space or _greylisted_ IP space. If you can't repro, then yes, there's something in your function code that's not happy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on the Kudo call that was a great help. It was actually due to a linked VNet . (Which i didnt mention in my post) It seems to be swallowing up outbound traffic and sending it on a very slow trip,  due to what looks like a bad config around dns.settings.

Answer (score 0):

(Copying Noel's comment as the answer)

> Thanks for the suggestion on the Kudo call that was a great help. **It was actually due to a linked VNet**. (Which i didnt mention in my post) It seems to be swallowing up outbound traffic and sending it on a very slow trip, due to what looks like a bad config around dns.settings.